# get the value from another values if value is nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
o0    v0   o1     v1      o3     v3
 -      -    -    -     2000    7   
103   2200  91    0     88      0
140   300   137  2200   131    2200
150   300   142  0      140    300
161   200   159  200    157     200
170   200   167  0       161    200
 -     -     173  200      187  300
```

Now . in this data-frame, Here I am trying to get the lowest value from these three values .By default offset_0 is always going to be the lowest.

Here following is the thing that I have tried

```
df_out["start"] = df_out['offset_0'].combine(df_out['offset_2'], lambda x1, x2: x2 if np.isnan(x1) else x1 )
```

Here it is only checking the `0 and 2`  and not the third one. so How do I add the offset 3 as well ?

So output would be

```
start
 7
103
118
132
139
```

Comment: Do you need `df_out["start"] = df.min(axis=1)` ?

Comment: but it is from row by row right ?

Comment: hmmm, because missing expected output not easy understand what need :(

Comment: updated output that

Comment: yop, then my soluton working nice.

Comment: Hi @ updated the question with thr proper data

Comment: @jezrael  please check

Comment: `df_out["start"] = df.filter(like='v').min(axis=1) `

Comment: will it work for v0,v1, v2 ?

Comment: with this , it is taking 0 as well if the row has that. Now that is the problem.. if one of the value is 0 or nan then it should take other value from that

Comment: if u see in my output first value is 7 and not 0

Comment: in sample data not possible, because there are only `-` (missing value) and `7` for first row

Comment: added a more data of the same

Comment: it is like take minimum but not 0 or nan like that

Comment: Please check once I have updated the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202325/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ganesh-kaspate).